# insert new child group or change the order in to a list of parent-child

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I would like to insert new child group or change the order in to a list of parent-child groups. Is this doable? I can add a child to the bottom of the list. But I dont know how to move the row.

groups:

```
 Center
  Category
    Rollup3MgrLn 
      Rollup4MgrLn 
         Rollup5
```

I added Rollup3MgrLn as a parent to Rollup4MgrLn and the tablix SSRS add a column for the new Rollup3MgrLn  group. Then I  insert a row above Rollup4MgrLn and move Rollup3MgrLn into the cell above Rollup4MgrLn  then delete the newly created column. But the Rollup4MgrLn and Rollup3MgrLn groups have the tablix region.

Answer (score 0):

no, you cant simply change the order of a grouping by simply selecting "move up" or "move down". What you can do is edit both groups and change their grouping expressions:

[image]

Comment: yes that is what I did. Edited the groups above and below the inserted rows so the parent child relationships are correct.  To reorder I think you have to recreate or edit all the groups from the top one changed on down.